# How to fetch parameters from GET URL in nodejs with two GET statements?

Tags: node.js, express, http

In Nodejs:

Both these statements need to be there for fetching all records and for fetching one record:

// All records:
`router.route('/').get((argReq, argRes)=>{ argRes.json( customerStruct.data ); } )`

// One record:
`router.route('/id:').get((argReq, argRes) => { argRes.json({'id' : '5' })});`

// From ThunderClient:
`http://localhost:7000/customerData/?id=0`

The above returns all values. It seems the second get request is not getting executed.

What is the way to correctly write all this?

Comment: `/` => all, `/:id` => one. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to clarify your question

Comment: @LinDu Well, you solved it. See my answer. :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error problem there:

For GETing one record, the `:` needs to be on the left side of the variable.
`/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to retrieve a single record by id, you should use `argReq.params.id`.
corrected code snippet you provided should look something like this:

```
// All records:
router.route('/').get((argReq, argRes)=>{ argRes.json( customerStruct.data ); } 
) 
// One record:
router.route('/:id').get((argReq, argRes) => { 
    argRes.json({'id' : customerStruct.data[argRes.params.id] });
});
```

assuming `customerStruct.data` is an array of all of your records